# View going out of screen in dynamic image views inside horizontal linear layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am programmatically inflating combination of ImageView and TextView inside my LinearLayout.My linear layout is under a horizontal scroll view. But when I set layout_gravity="center_horizontal" to the parent of my linear layout, the content inside linear layout going out of the screen.

See what is happening:

[image: screenshot]

I am using layout_gravity to achieve this

[image: this]

Without layout_gravity it appears like this

[image]

But if I use layout_gravity and there are many items inside that HorizontalScrollView then 1 or 2 items don't show. You can see the first uploaded image for understanding the scenario. In the first image I can't scroll more towards right and I can only see see of the ImageView and TextView combination and moreover, one more such combination is out of the screen completely.

Here's the xml structure

```
<HorizontalScrollView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="false"
                    android:scrollbars="none"
                    android:id="@+id/hotel_detail_services">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:id="@+id/imageViewLayout"
                            >
                        </LinearLayout>

                    </LinearLayout>
                </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Java manipulation

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<hotel_detail_model> hotel_detail_models) {
        super.onPostExecute(hotel_detail_models);
        LinearLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.imageViewLayout);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);


        if (hotel_detail_models.get(0).getTv()==1)
            addHotelSpeciality(layout,"TV",R.drawable.tv);
        if (hotel_detail_models.get(0).getAc()==1)
            addHotelSpeciality(layout,"AC",R.drawable.ac);
        if (hotel_detail_models.get(0).getGeyser()==1)
            addHotelSpeciality(layout,"Geyser",R.drawable.geyser);
        if (hotel_detail_models.get(0).getBus()==1)
            addHotelSpeciality(layout,"BUS",R.drawable.bus);
        if (hotel_detail_models.get(0).getCab()==1)
            addHotelSpeciality(layout,"CAB",R.drawable.cab);
        if (hotel_detail_models.get(0).getFood()==1)
            addHotelSpeciality(layout,"FOOD",R.drawable.food);
        if (hotel_detail_models.get(0).getRailway()==1)
            addHotelSpeciality(layout,"Train",R.drawable.train);
        if (hotel_detail_models.get(0).getAirport()==1)
            addHotelSpeciality(layout,"Airport",R.drawable.airport);
        if (hotel_detail_models.get(0).getMedical()==1)
            addHotelSpeciality(layout,"Medical",R.drawable.medical);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
    //Add Image Dynamically
    private void addHotelSpeciality(LinearLayout layout, String image_name, int image_id) {
        LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(hotel_details.this);
        ImageView image = new ImageView(hotel_details.this,null,R.style.dynamicImageHotel);
        TextView textView = new TextView(hotel_details.this,null,R.style.dynamicTextHotel);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen._25sdp),
                getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen._25sdp));
        params.weight = 1.0f;
        params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;


        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params2.weight = 1.0f;
        params2.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params3 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        params3.weight = 1.0f;
        params2.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;


        image.setLayoutParams(params);
        image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        textView.setLayoutParams(params2);
        image.setImageDrawable( getResources().getDrawable(image_id));
        textView.setText(image_name);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            textView.setTextAppearance(R.style.dynamicTextHotel);

        }else {
            textView.setTextAppearance(hotel_details.this,R.style.dynamicTextHotel);
        }
        // Adds the view to the layout
        linearLayout.addView(image);
        linearLayout.addView(textView);
        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        linearLayout.setLayoutParams(params3);           linearLayout.setPadding(getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen._15sdp),0,0,0);
        layout.addView(linearLayout);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that what you are trying to achieve by using `HorizontalScrollView`? ScrollViews allow content to be larger than the physical display so when you add enough "hotelSpecialities" it goes out of the screen and you can scroll through it. If you are trying to fit all the content on the screen then you would not use a `HorizontalScrollView`.

---

Okay now that I know what you are trying to achieve, putting your `ScrollView` inside a `RelativeLayout` will give you that.

This is what worked out for me

```
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_width="match_parent">
  <HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/hotel_detail_services"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="false"
    android:scrollbars="none">
    <LinearLayout
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="horizontal">
      <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/imageViewLayout"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
      </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
  </HorizontalScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

You can remove the parent `LinearLayout` for `imageViewLayout` too if you don't need it. Let me know if you need anymore help!

Comment: But the first content is not coming to the screen even after scrolling. That is what I mean. If you see the screenshot then the HorizontalScrollView is in a position that it cant't be scrolled more to left and yet I can't see an item.

Comment: Sorry, the screenshot didn't explain that. I have updated my answer to fix that

Comment: Not Working with the above changes

Comment: Sorry I was mistaken. What are you trying to achieve by using `layout_gravity="center_horizontal"`? This puts the layout horizontally center with respect to its parent, in this case the `HorizontalScrollView`